# Error con Base de Datos y Python

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x, python-3.7, pymysql

Hola tengo un problemas con bases de datos y python que no logro encontrar el error, el error qeu sale es el siguiente:

```
MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1")
```

mi codigo donde falla es este:

```
def create_xls(data):
    # Creo el XLSX
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    xls = df.to_excel('Planificador.xlsx', sheet_name='Resultados')
    # Coneccion a base de datos
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO tablas_excels (tablas) VALUE (%s)', (xls))
    mysql.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Saludos hermano, ¿podrías decirnos qué quieres lograr, por favor?

Comment: No entiendo porque no usas pandas para subir los datos, te ahorras el paso de convertirlo a excel, en lugar de to_excel usas to_sql pasandole un engine y listo, ya se ocupa pandas, tienes mas información en la documentación de pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def create_xls(data):
    # Creo el XLSX
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    xls = df.to_excel('Planificador.xlsx', sheet_name='Resultados')
    # Conexión a base de datos
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO tablas_excels (tablas) VALUE (%s);', (xls))
    mysql.connection.commit()
```